# How to correctly set up Angular2 template-driven form validation for min/max?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-form-validation

I'm trying to implement a new Angular component with template-driven form validation. I have been following the documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms), but cannot seem to replicate the results. Specifically, the div showing the error just doesn't appear when the input is invalid.

Here is the source code for context:

Template:

```
<mat-form-field class="input">
  <input matInput matTooltip="Float value between 0.0 and 1.0"
         type="number"
         placeholder="Confidence"
         min="0.0"
         max="1.0"
         [(ngModel)]="confidence"
         #value="ngModel">
  <mat-error *ngIf="value.invalid &&  (value.errors.min || value.errors.max)">
    Confidence must be an decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Relevant component code:

```
  metadata = {confidence: 0.0, ...};

  get confidence(): number {
    return this.metadata.confidence;
  }

  set confidence(confidenceIn: number) {
    this.metadata.confidence = confidenceIn;
  }
```

My understanding is that the line `#value="ngModel"` makes a local variable `value` containing the value of the input element it was declared on, which then allows me to reference `value` as in the following *ngIf directive to check for errors.

However, the mat-error element never shows up when the input value is out of range (less than 0, more than 1), so my understanding is probably wrong and/or I've implemented this incorrectly.

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strangely enough, the mat-error DOES appear if I change type=number to type=string, min to minlength, and max to maxlength. So this may be tied to the fact that I'm using numerical types, but I'm not sure why that would be different.